# How to allow the user to enter banned tags in textarea AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
<textarea name="textarea" id="text"></textarea>
```

Ajax:

```
$(function () {

    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {



      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'action.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          $(".success").show();
        }
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });

  });
```

The data entered in the textarea gets passed onto 'action.php' through the AJAX code above. It works fine but the problem is that when the user enters something like:

```
<input>
```

An error gets returned.

When the user enters things like:

```
<p>Test</p>
<h1>Test</h1>
<!----------->
<br>
etc
```

The code gets works. I believe it's because certain tags are banned. How do I allow the user to enter whatever he wants into the textarea.

Comment: Could you explain who or what is banning some tags?

Answer (score 0):

Use this `function`

```
function htmlencode(str) {
    return str.replace(/[&<>"']/g, function($0) {
        return "&" + {"&":"amp", "<":"lt", ">":"gt", '"':"quot", "'":"#39"}[$0] + ";";
    });
}
```

and pass the value of `textarea` in this function. It converts the HTML Entities into HTML Codes.

Comment: Thanks, but still cannot get this to work, when the user enters the <input> tag (for example), an error is returned and the data does not get sent.